# トライしてみて. Usage?

Tags: grammar

I just came across this in a magazine 'トライしてみて'.

I know it's saying 'try', but does it actually make grammatical sense? Would I be able to use that in a formal situation, or is it just to sound cute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the piece of the puzzle which you are missing is that トライする means "to try". ～する is the most common pattern for loans to turn into Japanese verbs (with some exceptions, like ググる etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is grammatically correct.  It's of the form `〜てみる` which means "to do 〜 and see how it goes/turns out".  `〜てみる` is fine for formal situations (actually, `〜てご[覧]{らん}ください` is even more formal), but the `トライする` is not.

However, `トライしてみて` is not just "cutesy" either.  It's perfectly fine to use in (most/all?) familiar situations.  For more formal situations, you can say `{やって・試して・試みて} + {みて・ご覧} + ください`.

Comment: I am just confused by the need to add 'トライ' to 'してみて'. Isn't it like saying 'try trying' or 'try doing trying'? surely 'してみて' on its own would be fine :/

Comment: @Heather Instead of thinking of してみて simply as "try", think of it as "do (eat/watch/listen to) something and see how it is".

Comment: Yeah I think トライしてみる is like [試]{ため}してみる, which is made of 試す(try) + してみる(try ~ing) but sounds perfectly fine